# List updation using while loop python

Tags: python, list, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying to update a list using while loop but its going in a infinite loop.
**Code**

```
li = [1,2,3,4]
max_time = [0,0,0,0]
li.sort()

if 2 in li:
    pos2 = li.index(2)
    max_time[0] = 2
    while(pos2<4 and li.index(2) != 3):
        if(li[pos2+1] == 3):
            max_time[1] = li[pos2+1]
            pos2 += 1
            continue
        elif(li[pos2+1] == 4 or li[pos2+1] == 5):
            max_time[2] = li[pos2+1]
            pos2 += 1
            continue
        else:
            max_time[3] = li[pos2+1]
            pos2 += 1
            continue
```

I want to check if the sorted list has 2, if there is 2 in the sorted list i want to check the next item unless 2 is not the last index in the list.
As the loop checks the next item and it is 3, it has to update the max_items list but it goes in a infinite loop.How can i avoid this?

EDIT : I want to take input of 4 numbers and output the max time possible on a 24-hour clock using those 4 numbers

Comment: There is no need for `continue` in your code, and `pos2+=1` can be placed after the `if` statement.

Comment: `li.index(2)` returns `1` it returns the index of the first object given, which is 2. `li = [1,2,3,4]` so `2` is in index `1`, You aren't changing the location of 2 in `li` so your condition of your while loop will always continue

Comment: *it has to update the max_items* - and how should look the final result?

Comment: Voting to close; program throws an exception rather than going into an infinite loop (ergo cannot reproduce)